# Apache ignite installation fails in kubernetes

Tags: ignite

I am trying to run Apache ignite: 2.5.0 inside the kubernetes cluster. My organization security policy doesn't allow to run as 'root' inside any container. I tried to add a security context (runAsNonRoot) in kubernetes yaml file. I am always getting the following error.

> cp: can't create '/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/libs/README.txt': File exists
>   cp: can't create '/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/libs/ignite-kubernetes-2.5.0.jar': Permission denied
>   cp: can't create '/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar': Permission denied
>   cp: can't create '/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar': Permission denied
>   cp: can't create '/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/libs/licenses/apache-2.0.txt': File exists
>   cp: can't create '/opt/ignite/apache-ignite-fabric/libs/licenses/ignite-kubernetes-licenses.txt': Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

As I know it should be fixed in Apache Ignite 2.7.6. Also as an option
you can try to modify your current Docker file as next (master version):

https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/docker/apache-ignite/Dockerfile